# Dipropylamine vs n-dipropylamine

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, amines

Are dipropylamine and *n*-dipropylamine the same thing? What are the differences or similarities in their chemical structures?

I think dipropylamine is $\ce{CH3CH2CH2NHCH2CH2CH3}$, but I am unsure about *n*-dipropylamine.

Comment: That would be N,N-dipropylamine. n is for linear hydrocarbons.

Comment: Well, the n- could potentially refer to the propyl group. It's not perfectly clear from the question, but I suspect it is not to indicate the propyl groups are on the N. There's no other place to put them...

Answer (score 4):

[Chemspider](http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.7564.html) as well as [Pubchem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/dipropylamine#section=Names-and-Identifiers&fullscreen=true) list the names “dipropylamine” and “*n*-dipropylamine” as synonyms. Hence, it is likely that both names have actually been used in the literature for the same compound. However, that doesn’t mean that such names are generally acceptable or in accordance with any past or present nomenclature rules.

The name “dipropylamine” corresponds to the traditional method that was in accordance with the IUPAC recommendations from [1979](http://www.acdlabs.com/iupac/nomenclature/79/r79_918.htm) as well as [1993](http://www.acdlabs.com/iupac/nomenclature/93/r93_402.htm).

The name “*n*-dipropylamine” is not in accordance with IUPAC nomenclature. It was probably used to emphasize the difference to “diisopropylamine”.

According to Subsection P-62.2.2.1 of the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001),* functional parent names like “dipropylamine” are now deprecated. Nevertheless, in general nomenclature, similar names for amines may be formed by prefixing the names of the substituent groups $\ce{R-{}}$, $\ce{R'-{}}$, and $\ce{R''-{}}$ to the parent hydride name ‘amine’, but the prefixes are set off by parentheses to distinguish the names from the above-mentioned deprecated names. Therefore, a correct name for the compound that is given in the question is “(dipropyl)amine”.

The preferred IUPAC name (PIN) is generated substitutively using the name of the parent hydride and the suffix ‘amine’ with further *N*-substitution. Therefore, the PIN for the compound that is given in the question is “*N*-propylpropan-1-amine”.

[image: N-propylpropan-1-amine]